# Não consigo salvar um Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma página que pode ter acesso não permitido, aberta para leitura ou aberta para leitura e escrita. Ainda que a página seja totalmente fechada, o dono da mesma pode escolher alguns usuários do sistema que poderão ter acesso a esta. Essas exceções podem receber permissões de escrita ou escrita e leitura, para isso, utilizei um dictionary aonde a key será o usuário que terá permissão e a String indicará qual nível de acesso ele tem nessa página.

Problema: O dictionary parece não conseguir ser salvo no banco, apenas na Action que está sendo executada, assim, não passa do Post da tela de edição da página.

Model da Página:

```
public class Fluxo
{
    [Key]
    public int FluxoID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dê um nome a fluxo")]
    [Display(Name = "Título")]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Dono do fluxo")]
    public virtual Usuario Dono { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Topico")]
    public String TopicoPertencente { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Visibilidade")]
    public String Visibilidade { get; set; }

    public virtual IDictionary<Usuario, String> Permitidos { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Informacao> Informacoes { get; set; }

    public object[] UsuarioID { get; internal set; }
}
```

Trecho do FluxoController/Edit:

```
    [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include =   "FluxoID,Nome,TopicoPertencente,Visibilidade,desassociar")] ViewModels.Fluxo vwfluxo)
            {
              if (ModelState.IsValid)
              {
                Fluxo fluxo = db.Fluxo.Include(f => f.Dono).Where(fl => fl.FluxoID.Equals(vwfluxo.FluxoID)).FirstOrDefault();
                ...

                // Até essa parte, tudo vai bem, porém, a Action termina e o Dictionary se perde.
               fluxo.Permitidos = Selecionados; //Selecionados foi um Dictionary montado para salvar os usuários selecionados, essa lista irá preencher os Permitidos do objeto.

                db.Entry(fluxo).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Ao sair da Action, fluxo.Permitidos fica nulo. Não sei se está faltando algo para salvar com sucesso, sou iniciante na linguagem e é bem possível que aconteça algo do tipo, mas minha opinião é que tem algum problema em tentar salvar um dictionary no banco, não há nenhum atributo em db.Fluxo que pareça estar relacionado a esse dictionary.
Desculpem se algo está complicado para entender, primeiro post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Procure não ficar triste com o que vou dizer: o Entity Framework não mapeia dicionários.

Crie uma classe associativa assim:

```
public class FluxoUsuario
{
    [Key]
    public int FluxoUsuarioID { get; set; }
    public int FluxoID { get; set; }
    public int UsuarioID { get; set; }

    public virtual Fluxo Fluxo { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

E `Fluxo.cs`:

```
public class Fluxo
{
    [Key]
    public int FluxoID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dê um nome a fluxo")]
    [Display(Name = "Título")]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Dono do fluxo")]
    public virtual Usuario Dono { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Topico")]
    public String TopicoPertencente { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Visibilidade")]
    public String Visibilidade { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FluxoUsuario> UsuariosPermitidos { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Informacao> Informacoes { get; set; }

    public object[] UsuarioID { get; internal set; }
}
```

E `Usuario.cs`:

```
public class Usuario
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<FluxoUsuario> FluxosPermitidos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ok, entendi o ponto, mas ainda estou com uma dúvida, eu preciso diferenciar as permissões, com isso eu consigo ver que saberei qual usuário tem permissão em qual fluxo, mas ainda não sei como poderei fazer para diferenciar as permissões ("Ler e escrever", "Apenas leitura"). Devo acrescentar um atributo na classe associativa?

Comment: Sim. Minha sugestão, aliás, é um `Enum`.

Comment: Tudo certo! Apenas adicionei um enum tipoPermissao { Ler, LerEscrever}.